# AngularJs throws error after minify

Tags: angularjs, laravel, gulp, minify

After minifying my angularjs code i get an error:

**Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: t**

*Code works only if run gulp **without** --production flag* .

```
//All dependencies used in below are minified in a single file

(function(){
 angular
    .module('app', [
        'ngMessages',
        'ngStorage',
        'ngAnimate',
        'toastr',
        'ngSanitize'
        ]); 
})();
```

**Service code**

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular
.module('app')
  .factory('dataservice', dataservice);

  dataservice.$inject = ['$http','$localStorage','toastr'];

  function dataservice($http,$localStorage,toastr) {

          //Code inside this function uses all 3 dependencies injected
  }
  })();
```

**Controller code**

```
(function(){

  'use strict';

  angular
   .module('app')
   .controller('LoginController',LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$localStorage','dataservice','toastr','$scope','$sanitize'];

   function LoginController($localStorage,dataservice,toastr,$scope,$sanitize)    { 

        /// All 5 dependencies injected here are used inside this function.
    }
})();
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time raising the link bc of the east coast DDOS going on right now, but check out ng-annotate -- it resolves the issue of minification breaking Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the `$inject` property before you register your modules:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    dataservice.$inject = ['$http','$localStorage','toastr'];

    function dataservice($http,$localStorage,toastr) {

          //Code inside this function uses all 3 dependencies injected
    }

    angular
      .module('app')
      .factory('dataservice', dataservice);
})();
```

Or you can even get rid of `$inject` with adding [`ng-annotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) as a build step before minification.

Comment: I should try ng-annotate , even this code throwed the same error.

Comment: yeah, it's always better to use strict mode which would enforce it.

Comment: @TamasHegedus yes i did , now im trying to get ng-annonate working on laravel-elixir